# How to stop a custom control bound to a business object from updating unnecessarily?

Tags: winforms, data-binding, custom-controls

I have a Windows Forms application with a custom control for entering dates. This is inherits from Textbox and implements a Value property for binding to the underlying business object.

Everything works well except that when the control validates it updates the bound property, even when it hasn't changed. This is a problem because I'm using Entity Framework and the change to the entity's property causes the corresponding field in the database to be updated every time a user opens and closes the form hosting this control.

Here is the code:

```
Public Class TextBoxDate
Inherits TextBox

Public ValueChanged As EventHandler

Private _dateValue As Nullable(Of Date) = Nothing
<Bindable(True)> _
<Category("Appearance")> _
Public Property Value() As Nullable(Of Date)
    ' Bind to the Value property instead of the Text property, as the latter will not allow
    ' the user to delete the contents of the textbox. The Value property provides support for nulls.
    Get
        Value = _dateValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Nullable(Of Date))
        _dateValue = value
        ' Update the text in the textbox
        If value.HasValue Then
            Text = CDate(value).ToShortDateString
        Else
            Text = vbNullString
        End If
        OnValueChanged()
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub OnValueChanged()
    If (ValueChanged IsNot Nothing) Then
        ValueChanged(Me, New EventArgs())
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxDate_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Enter

    _userEntered = True

End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxDate_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Leave

    _userEntered = False

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnValidating(ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)

    If _userEntered Then
        If Me.TextLength = 0 Then
            ' Null value will be saved to the database via the bound Value property
            If Value IsNot Nothing Then
                Value = Nothing
            End If
        Else
            Dim dateValue As Date
            If Date.TryParseExact(Text, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dateValue) Then
                If Value Is Nothing Or (dateValue <> Value) Then
                    Value = CDate(Text)
                End If
            Else
                e.Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

    MyBase.OnValidating(e)

End Sub

End Class
```

This is driving me mad. Any help would be much appreciated.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

When you define the binding of the textbox you can specify the [DataSourceUpdateMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode) of the Binding object, for example

```
Binding custNameBinding = new Binding("Text", ds, "customers.custName");
custNameBinding.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
custNameTextBox.DataBindings.Add(custNameBinding);
```

The MSDN documentation says "Data source is updated whenever the value of the control property changes."